# SCT-013-000 with Arduino MKR 1300

Tags: arduino, energy-monitoring-systems

Has anyone tried to use this particular sensor (SCT-013-000) with that particular Arduino (MKR 1300)? Cause I keep getting different results when connecting Arduino UNO and then trying the MKR, both connected to the 5 V.
As for the resistors I have been using both 10 kΩ resistors and the 33 Ω for burden, calibration at 60.6 and sampling at 1480. Basically, everything configurated with the help of the guide on this [website](https://learn.openenergymonitor.org/electricity-monitoring/ct-sensors/introduction).

But this isn’t the only issue with this particular set (MKR 1300 + sensor), I tested with an amperometric clamp a 6 A heater and the sensor values were also quite different (8 A on the sensor instead of around 6 A), only when I got the calibration to 38.8 it got close values, but I don’t think it works for every current, but since the calibration should be a fixed value based on the burden resistor and the sensor it doesn’t make much sense for me.

Comment: Which sensor do you have exactly? Because SCT-013-000 rated for 0-100 mA  and SCT-013-000V is rated for 0-100 A input current.

Comment: @BenceKaulics SCT-013-000 with a ratio of 100A:0.05A